# How to search a value which can returns true in WHERE condition OR in HAVING condition?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, group-concat, having

I want to search multi vars that could be true in WHERE condition or in HAVING condition in a group_concat table. Something like this:

```
SELECT
    article.id,
    article.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name order by tags.name) AS nameTags,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.id order by tags.id) AS idTags
FROM
    article
    LEFT JOIN ....
    LEFT JOIN ....
WHERE article.name LIKE '%var1%' OR HAVING nameTags LIKE '%var1%' AND
WHERE article.name LIKE '%var2%' OR HAVING nameTags LIKE '%var2%'
GROUP BY id
```

**Is there some way possible or is it better to do 2 querys?**

This query:

```
SELECT
    article.id,
    article.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name order by tags.name) AS nameTags,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.id order by tags.id) AS idTags
FROM
    article
    LEFT JOIN ....
    LEFT JOIN ....
WHERE
(article.name LIKE '%var1%' OR  tags.name LIKE '%var1%') AND
(article.name LIKE '%var2%' OR  tags.name LIKE '%var2%')
GROUP BY id
```

Find what I search, but I must do a second query to show results as I want.

*sorry if question is repeated, I didn't know how to ask it, so I did'nt know how to search for it. Sorry my english too!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    article.id,
    article.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name order by tags.name) AS nameTags,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.id order by tags.id) AS idTags,
    MAX(IF(article.name LIKE '%var1%',1,0)) AS var1match,
    MAX(IF(article.name LIKE '%var2%',1,0)) AS var2match
FROM
    article
    LEFT JOIN ....
    LEFT JOIN ....
GROUP BY id
HAVING
    (nameTags LIKE '%var1%' OR var1match=1)
    OR (nameTags LIKE '%var2%' OR var2match=1)
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Didn't know this function! I will study to understand it well!
I can't give you points yet, sorry, and thanks a lot!

Comment: Just had to add comma between the MAX itens